# Square bracketed expression is evaluated differently in M365 vs Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

The company I work for has recently moved from Office 2016 to M365. Some of our macro-enabled spreadsheets use bracketed expressions as a shortcut to the Application.Evaluate method. For example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim msg As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    
    If Target.Columns.Count > 100 Then
        Dim row As Range
        For Each row In Target.Rows
            RemoveRowBorders row:=row.row, firstColumn:=[colSourceDevice], lastColumn:=[colItemNumber]
        Next
        
        UpdateItemNumbers startingRow:=[rowStart], maxRange:=[maxRange]
        GoTo My_Exit
    End If
    
    If Target.Column >= [colSourceDevice] And Target.Column <= [colItemNumber] Then
        SetCalculations cellRange:=Target
    End If
    
My_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    msg = "An error occurred on cell auto-update: " & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    MsgBox msg
    Resume My_Exit
End Sub
```

"colSourceDevice" is a named range/object that refers to a formula that returns the column number and the bracketed expression is a shortcut to call the Application.Evaluate method. The formula referred to in "colSourceDevice" is:

```
=VALUE(COLUMN('HS - Main'!$A$2))
```

**In Excel 2016, the bracketed expression returns the column number (Variant/Double).**

**In M365 Excel the bracketed expression returns an array (Variant/Variant) with one item (Variant/Double).**

*In M365 Excel, this results in a Type mismatch error.*

I can use the object model approach instead of the bracketed expression and get the intended result:

```
Application.Evaluate("colSourceDevice")(1) 'returns column number (Variant/Double)
```

**Why does the square bracketed expression return a different data type in M365 vs Excel 2016?**

**EDIT:**

As chris neilsen alluded to, there was a major change to the Excel calculation engine in 2018.

See here:
[Excel: Microsoft unveils Dynamic upgrades](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2018/nov/microsoft-excel-dynamic-upgrades-201819867.html)

Another approach to achieving legacy behavior for square bracketed expressions is to prepend the new implicit intersection operator (@) to the named range within the brackets:

```
    If Target.Column >= [@colSourceDevice] And Target.Column <= [@colItemNumber] Then
        SetCalculations cellRange:=Target
    End If
```

...as described here:
[Microsoft makes major Dynamic Arrays modifications](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/feb/excel-dynamic-arrays-modifications-201920674.html)

Comment: FWIW I suspect the issue has nothing to do with 32/64bit, but rather the change from Excel 2016 to 355.  This introduced Dynamic Ranges, which is a fundamental change in how formulas work.

Comment: Without seeing your Named Range formula it's hard to suggest a fix for _this_ issue.  On the broader issue, I'm with freeflow on this, maybe it's time for a major refactoring

Comment: @freeflow - I do have Rubberduck and I love it! This is one of many macro-enabled spreadsheets floating around here that I didn't write but yes there are many opportunities for improvement. Unfortunately, Rubberduck doesn't offer a quick-fix for this particular issue but it does suggest "using the host application's model instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue has nothing to do with 32/64bit, but rather the change from Excel 2016 to 355. This introduced Dynamic Ranges, which is a fundamental change in how formulas work.

Since you haven't provided the Formula in your Named range, I'm going to base this answer on an example formula, which may or may not reflect yours.

```
colSourceDevice Refers to = =COLUMN()
```

[image]

This exhibits the behaviour you describe

[image]

What it's actually doing is returning a Dynamic Array of 1 element.

To return that value as a Variant, modify the Named range by wrapping it in `INDEX`

```
colSourceDevice2 Refers to = =INDEX(COLUMN(),1,1)
```

[image]

The result is now what you  want

[image]

---

Disclaimer:

All that said, this is a band aid fix for some ill-conceived code.  My advise: refactor your code to eliminate this and other bad practices.

Comment: The Named Range formula is in the original post. "=VALUE(COLUMN('HS - Main'!$A$2)) "

Comment: Wrapping the formula with "INDEX" does the trick... just from the formula side instead of the VBA side. I have modified the original post so that there is only one question. Hopefully the edit clarifies my question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You got me pointed in the right direction so I marked your response as the answer... I did some more digging and it looks like an update in the Excel 365 calculation engine introduced new Dynamic Arrays. One way to get the legacy behavior is to prepend the named range value in the brackets with the new implicit intersection operator, @.